# The term 'node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm getting an error while trying to create an angular project. 
This is the first time I have installed node.js and all the testing was successful.

```html
PS D:\ASP.NET Core & Angular\AngularAPI> ng new Angular7
& : The term 'node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Nahian\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1:15 char:5
+   & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" $args
+     ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The environment variables were set according to the instruction as well

[image]

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have Installed the node.js and angular

[image]

Comment: You're missing Node.js, it looks like...

Comment: @Brad I have downloaded and installed the node.js

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are missing the `path` for NodeJs. Try adding the path to `environment variables`

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio Code should be restarted after adding the path to environment variables. Thanks @saitama

Comment: i have node js path among my environment variables. whts wrong with that?